# Month jumping on date selection using react-date-range

Tags: reactjs, next.js, date-range

I'm using *DateRangePicker* from [react-date-range](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-range#daterangepicker--daterange) in a next.js project.

You can see the expected behavior on their [demo page](https://hypeserver.github.io/react-date-range/#!/DateRangePicker/1): if you select any date from the month on the right, the months stay in place. [*Here's a video*](https://www.screencast.com/t/NJkEXXYz).

But in my project, the month from the right jumps to the left on date selection ([*as you can see it in this video*](https://www.screencast.com/t/beAqdTNk7)).
I've made a simple [demo here](https://csb-3e52n-l3tgwabop.vercel.app/) by copying code from their demo page:

```
import { addDays } from "date-fns";
import { useState } from "react";
import { DateRangePicker } from "react-date-range";
import "react-date-range/dist/styles.css"; // main style file
import "react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css"; // theme css file

export default function IndexPage() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([
    {
      startDate: new Date(),
      endDate: addDays(new Date(), 7),
      key: "selection"
    }
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <DateRangePicker
        onChange={(item) => setState([item.selection])}
        showSelectionPreview={true}
        moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
        months={2}
        ranges={state}
        direction="horizontal"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Here you can see the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-oskar-3e52n?file=/pages/index.js) from my demo page.
Any idea or solution to stop this behavior is welcome! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The last version of react-date-range (14.0) add a feature to solve this problem. Just add this prop to your component.

```
preventSnapRefocus="disabled"
```

But this could show you an error message on console. The best options for me was just put

```
preventSnapRefocus
```

(yes, puting "disabled" or nothing, the behavior is the same... weird for me)

> https://github.com/hypeserver/react-date-range/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 0):

This is an odd one---I'm sure someone more familiar with Next.js can update this question to flesh out *exactly* why this error occurs, but for now I have identified a fix and a *possible* explanation.

I plugged your code into a `create-react-app` instance and it worked fine, funny enough:
[Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/date-picker-react-6bhdn).

I tested your same code and observed the same odd formatting. I also noticed that the dates generated by `next.js` were curiously *not accurate*; for example, it wouldn't start with today (it was off by one date, starting the selection on 'tomorrow'; this was not the case with the `create-react-app` version which accurately started the initial selection) so something is up with the rendering. My best guess: `next.js` may not be re-rendering the `<DateRangePicker />` and/or its css values (or the component in general?)---at least not when the component is initialized?---so I injected the initial data selection on load with `useEffect` and added a stringified version of the state as a key to the container div to force a re-render and it no longer displays the odd selection css:

```
import { addDays } from "date-fns";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { DateRangePicker } from "react-date-range";
import "react-date-range/dist/styles.css"; // main style file
import "react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css"; // theme css file

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {               {/* <---- useEffect to update state on init */}
    if (state.length === 0) {
      setState([
        {
          startDate: new Date(),
          endDate: addDays(new Date(), 7),
          key: "selection"
        }
      ]);
    }
  }, [state, setState]);

  return (
    <div key={JSON.stringify(state)}>     {/* <-- added key here, to force rerender */}
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <DateRangePicker
        onChange={(item) => setState([item.selection])}
        showSelectionPreview={true}
        moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
        months={2}
        ranges={state}
        direction="horizontal"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And it worked: [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-sun-ynrhc?file=/pages/index.js), [demo page](https://ynrhc.sse.codesandbox.io/).

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I can still see that unwanted behavior in all 3 links that you provided. In the last two, I can only select a single date instead of a range. I've updated my question with video links to visualize those behaviors.

Comment: @BarnaTekse Oh I see! I thought you were referring to the jenky / persistent css styling of the dates that are selected. OK, let me poke at this a bit and see what I can do.

Comment: if youre referring date was off by one day, i think you can check  `new Date()` function as it might show you the date with the server timezone.

You can try `console.log` the date and compare its value with your system date